# UnauthorizedAccessException when programatically accessing mp3 file in WinRT XAML app

Tags: vb.net, xaml, exception, windows-runtime

Problem accessing mp3 files in WinRT app.

'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurs when app tries to open a mp3 file by name in the same folder as a file returned by FileOpenPicker. Put another way, the user picks an info file in Documents with the same name as a mp3 file. App opens the info file just fine but cannot open the mp3 file.

For example: I have a pair of files (file1.info) and (file1.mp3). A filepicker allows selecting a (*.info) file.

The user selects (file1.info). The app then opens both (file1.info) and (file1.mp3). Both files reside in a DocumentsLibrary folder, but are NOT in the MusicLibrary. The problem is when I try to open (file1.mp3) I get the 'UnauthorizedAccessException'.

To prepro the issue:

Files:
    Copy an mp3 file to Documents.
    Create a text file with the same base name as the mp3 file and change its extension to .info.

In Package.appxmanifest > Declarations add a 'File Type Associations' declaration. Check 'Open is safe'. Add

supported file types '.mp3' and '.info'. Leave 'Content type' empty.

Code:

```
Dim file as StorageFile
Dim fileopenpicker As FileOpenPicker
Dim infofile As StorageFile
Dim mp3file As StorageFile 
Dim filename As String
fileopenpicker = New FileOpenPicker()
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".info")
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3")
fileopenpicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
file = Await fileopenpicker.PickSingleFileAsync()
If file.Path.EndsWith(".info") Then
    infofile = file
    filename = file.Path.Substring(0, file.Path.Length - 4) & "mp3"
    ' This command fails with 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
    mp3file = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename)
Else 'file is an mp3 file
    mp3file = file
    filename = file.Path.Substring(0, file.Path.Length - 3) & "info"
    ' This command succeeds!
    infofile = Await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename)
End If
```

So it appears that there is some specific problem with opening an mp3 file when the file is not actually chosen by the fileopenpicker.

Comment: More info. Seems very strange, but tied to the mp3 file's name. Using different file names (same actual mp3 file contents copied from place to place) or placing it in different subfolders seems to effect whether an UnauthorizedAccessException occurs in GetFileFromPathAsync. However, I have never seen a fail when passing an *.info file name to GetFileFromPathAsync. There must be something peculiar and inconsistent with the way GetFileFromPathAsync handles mp3 file names.

Comment: Seems necessary to folder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsyncfile.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("\")) first and then folder.GetFileAsync(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\") + 1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked this issue with an app that has the capability Documents Library and the filetypes .mp3 and .info declared. I figured out that it seems to be a very strange bug. If you pass the path to the documents library folder using an uppercase drive letter after having opened a FileOpenPicker  you get an UnauthorizedAccessException. Using the path with a lowercase drive letter works. Strangely you can use an uppercase drive letter before having opened a FileOpenPicker.

So the workaround is to lowercase the path.

Here's the code I used (C#):

```
// Trying to get some files from the documents library
// Note: F:\Program Data is my primary documents library folder
string mp3FilePath = @"F:\Program Data\2Mann1Maus.mp3";

// This works even if the drive letter is uppercase
StorageFile file1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(mp3FilePath);

// It also works with a lowercase drive letter
string infoFilePath = @"f:\Program Data\2Mann1Maus.info";
StorageFile file2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(infoFilePath);

FileOpenPicker fileopenpicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".info");
fileopenpicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
fileopenpicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
StorageFile file = await fileopenpicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file.Path.EndsWith(".info"))
{
   string filename = file.Path.Substring(0, file.Path.Length - 4) + "mp3";   

   // This works
   string testFileName1 = filename.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + 
      filename.Substring(1,  filename.Length - 1);
   StorageFile mp3file1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(testFileName1);

   // This works as well
   string testFileName2 = filename.ToLower();
   StorageFile mp3file2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(testFileName2); 

   // This does cause an UnauthorizedAccessException
   StorageFile mp3file3 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
}
else
{
   StorageFile mp3file = file;
   String filename = file.Path.Substring(0, file.Path.Length - 3) + "info"; 

   // This works
   string testFileName1 = filename.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + 
      filename.Substring(1, filename.Length - 1);
   StorageFile infoFile1 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(testFileName1); 

   // This works as well
   string testFileName2 = filename.ToLower();
   StorageFile infoFile2 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(testFileName2); 

   // This does cause an UnauthorizedAccessException
   StorageFile infoFile3 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
}
```

Comment: In my testing, I also found that a change in case of a character in the path effects whether it succeeds. So, I had C:\Users\%username$\Docuemnts\Temp\ containing the files. Some file names would fail and others would succeed. But changing the folder name to 'temp' instead of 'Temp' would would fix it for some files but break it for others. It must be a problem with ID hash algorithm WinRT uses. My solution was to get a StorageFolder object first, and then use that to get the StorageFile with folder.GetFileAsync().

Comment: So far, I have not had any failures when using StorageFolder when testing with a dozen mp3 file names. Also, FYI for anyone watching this, when running in Win 8 Local, DocumentsLibrary is not necessary, but when using the Simulator it is. I'll need to check more than a dozen files to be sure which solution works best.

Comment: For those of who want to load file with `GetFileFromPathAsync()` and have trouble to get `UnauthorizedException`, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17252426/361100 article also.