# Load File as storagefile from Local drive (resource)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing Windows 8 app using C#.
Here I am picking the file from my desired Location Using FilePicker,
I Know the path of file which I picked from Local drive.

I want to use the File as a Storage file.

```
  StorageFile Newfile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(Path); // Path is file path

  StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync(Path);
```

But this is for only where my project located & another one for Load file from Pictures Library.
Can any one give me the right Way.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you facing problem, your question is unclear. Are you using `PickSingleFileAsync()` of `FileOpenPicker` class ?

Comment: @Xyroid I don't know how to How to pick file if I know the file path, I mean like this **E:\E Books\Final code\file.zip** .
My question is how to get file as StorageFile Using Url..
I tried in google I didn't get relevent answer.
I hope U here I get answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinRT has `GetFileFromPathAsync()` method of class `StorageFile`, but you can not open any file with that method. Only option you have is to use `StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList` class. Which is useful to get the token for all the files that was saved to either [most recently used files list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.mostrecentlyusedlist) or [future access list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist). To save token for the which was accessed from `FileOpenPicker`, you need to use `StorageApplicationPermissions` class. Here I'm giving you how to save token for a file & how to retrieve  token for & access that file.

To save token

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Add to most recently used list with metadata (For example, a string that represents the date)
    string mruToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.Add(file, "20130622");

    // Add to future access list without metadata
    string faToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);  
}
else
{
    // The file picker was dismissed with no file selected to save
}
```

To retrieve file using token

<s>StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList MRU = new StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList();</s>

StorageFile file = await MRU.GetFileAsync(token);

**UPDATE**

```
await StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(token);
```

Comment: Thanks you for neat explanation, But Here my intention is different from this.
I am loading multiple Files using `PickMultipleFilesAsync();` & displaying those values in Gridview, Here if I select a single item in GV  using `Item_click` I am going Get that values using `ClickedItem`.
Here I know the FilePath & file name like values only.
Hope U understand the Situation.
Why I don't use `GetFileFromPathAsync()`

Comment: `GetFileFromPathAsync()` is allows only with path related to known folders (libraries) & app's local & temp folder. You can bind the token to gridview's item (don't display it though), and you can get that token while `ItemClick` event, then you can open the file.

Comment: This is Code block in `ItemClick`
`ItemEpub.EpubItems output = e.ClickedItem as ItemEpub.EpubItems;
 
  EpubPathToken = output.mruToken;  

  StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList MRU = new StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList(output);  

  StorageFile Epubfile = await MRU.GetFileAsync(EpubPathToken);`  

  I am getting error in `new StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList(output);`

  **Error is** : 'Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: Here Is my code [http://pastebin.com/Wsx1tRJa]

Can you give me any idea for this error, Thanks

Comment: You are initializing constructor in wrong way. Constructor of class `StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList` doesn't take answer, read my answer carefully. Read "To retrieve file using token" part to know how to get `StorageFile` object from token.

Comment: In your code I have a simple question, Which token value U are using in the `StorageFile file = await MRU.GetFileAsync(token);` whether **mruToken** or **fatoken**. I hope It is **mruToken**.
& then what is the use of giving the value of Date in `MostRecentlyUsedList`.

Still I didn't get success using the `MostRecentlyUsedList`.
I tried creating a class for `MostRecentlyUsedList`.
But there is no `GetfileAsync()` in it.

Comment: I am passing `mruToken` token. Date in MostRecentlyUsedList is optional parameter. Have you added `using Windows.Storage.AccessCache;` ?

Comment: Yes, I added.
Which parameters I have to add to 
`StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList MRU = new StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList();` ?


\
Error:
'Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I did a mistake, see the answer, I've updated it

Comment: Yes, Finally It worked with you. I am getting the file total details like path etc..
Really I excited to see the result, It is nice; Using the path I am Loading my Epub file.
After that I am going to Extract the file to my Package folder using `ApplicationData`.
In the mean while of extraction I am getting Exception of `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.  
[http://sdrv.ms/12dwJDy ]

Comment: Please post your query as a new question.

Comment: Yes, Sure. I think Because of using `StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList` 
It is giving Exception, Can you give me out for this.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289853/exception-of-unauthorized-while-using-mostrecentlyusedlist-in-metro-apps ]
Thanks

Comment: Kind MSDN tutorial link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh972344.aspx